# Options to create a reverse geocode system using OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I need to create a local reverse geocode service for my specific country using open source maps.

My first option is OpenStreetMap so I downloaded my country PBF file.

Can anyone give any idea on how to start using this data? or other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already various [search engines for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) available. The most popular one currently is [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). It supports both geocoding and reverse geocoding.

Comment: Yes i have used online version of it, and it work great. Now do you know y I can host my own Nominatim server with local PBF data under windows?

Comment: See [Nominatim/Installation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). You will very likely need a Linux machine, which could be a VM inside your Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start of by reading the [wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page), I guess it would be interesting to find out which node / way / relation tags you would use as an input. Apart from that you should have an understanding of the best data structures for the task, I guess you want to perform nearest neighbor queries, so you might need to implement / use an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) for that...